# How to send beeline output to sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, beeline, sqoop2

I am struggling to send beeline output to apache sqoop tool. I guess Apache sqooop can read data from where data sits on Hadoop cluster.But beeline can query data and output the data into where hadoop client is running.

Is it possible to send beeline output directly to hadoop cluster or instruct apache sqoop to read data from machine where hadoop client not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate on the requirement?
I assume that you are running a query on hive via beeline. Do you want to move the result into same cluster HDFS storage or a different cluster/FS ?

If it's in the same cluster, then you can create an external table and run a select insert query. If not, please elaborate on the usecase.